# Generating Corrupt pdf File

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script

I am using apps script to generate a pdf file from an HTML template.  Here is my pdf generate code:

```
DriveApp.createFile('pdfReceipt', template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).getContent(), MimeType.PDF)
```

This generates a pdf file that I can see in preview, when I view it in preview it says

`Whoops! There was a problem loading more pages!`  On top of the message I see the pdf file properly formatted and it looks fine.

When I try downloading the file, I can't open it on my box, it claims the file is corrupted.

Does anyone have experience with this in apps script? I am not sure on how to begin debugging.

[image]

If you read the comments of this post, I get this output from this basic line on two different google accounts in two separate Apps Script files:

```
 DriveApp.createFile('New PDF File', 'Hello, world!', MimeType.PDF)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it's because of the SandboxMode
Normally this will work :

```
function myFunction() {
  var template = HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
      .evaluate().getContent();
  DriveApp.createFile('pdfReceipt', template, MimeType.PDF)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I tried that now, and earlier and am getting the same result.  I just tried running     DriveApp.createFile('pdfReceipt', 'helloWorld', MimeType.PDF)  in a new script file and am getting the same result.

Comment: You have the problem somewhere else then.  

DriveApp.createFile('New PDF File', 'Hello, world!', MimeType.PDF)
is definitely working

Comment: I took a screenshot and added it above, I switched google accounts, created a fresh script file and ran a function with the code you linked in your comment and get the same error and output when I go to view it.  You are not getting this with your code?

Comment: Alright ! Got the same error too. You can preview the file, but after download you can't open it

Comment: Correct! I have no clue why or any idea on how to debug it.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Please star this issue https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5507

Comment: Done. I'm curious what's the reason behind it.